# How can I get response code that was called from JS (ajax) in WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have an url that is called from JS (ajax) inside WebView. I need to know if this URLs response code is 200. So I tried with `shouldInterceptRequest()`, but this only returns the url but not the response code.